# Почему нельзя обойтись без прототипа метода в классе? С++

Tags: c++, классы, методы

У нас есть определение класса `Point`. И я хочу объявить не в теле этого класса некоторый метод:

```
void Point::set(int x, int y)
{
    /*здесь код*/
}
```

Для чего в классе `Point` я должен буду прописать прототип этого метода, разве то, что я пишу `Point::` не говорит компилятору о том, что у данного класса есть такой метод?

Comment: так теперь я задам вам вопрос: зачем используют вообще прототипы функций или методов класса/структуры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Point::` - это называется поиск имени с квалификатором (qualified name lookup) и говорит о том, что объявление символа, имя которого идет после `::`, следует искать в `Point`. О том, что в у данного класса есть такой метод и какая у него сигнатура, компилятору говорит объявление метода в теле класса.

Класс считается завершенным (complete), когда его определение закончено. Собственно добавление метода во вне определения класса не может работать в С++ по многим причинам. Хотя бы потому, что для этого нет синтаксиса модификатора доступа, или например `static` имеет иной смысл вне определения класса.

Answer (score 1):

Виртуальные функции по понятным причинам должны быть все объявлены в одном месте.

Специальные члены классов (копирующие и перемещающие конструкторы и операторы присваивания, и деструкторы) - может и могли бы быть объявлены отдельно, но это создавало бы большую путаницу.

Для остальных функций есть как минимум еще одна проблема - что делать с непубличными полями/методами? Открывать к ним доступ для объявленных позднее методов? Тогда смысл теряется.

Если не учитывать последнее, то невозможность добавлять обычные функции в классы - это произвольное ограничение. Но это в чем-то удобно: если пишешь `foo.bar()`, то можешь быть уверенным, что это метод из оригинального класса, а не дописанный кем-то снаружи.

[Были поползновения](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4165.pdf) в похожую сторону - не разрешить дописывать функции в класс, но сделать синтаксис `f(a,x,y)`, `a.f(x,y)` и `a->f(x,y)` более-менее взаимозаменямым. Но в стандарт это не приняли.